# TableView only showing one cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I only see one cell in my TableView.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.menuItems = @[@"menu,favorite,animal,spase,nature,car,minimal"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

     return [self.menuItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     static NSString * indetifier = @"Cell";

    MFCustomCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indetifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[MFCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:indetifier];

    }
    ///this work
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.imageCell.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu.png"];
        cell.labelCell.text = @"work";
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        ///this does not work
        ///dont see this cell     indexPath.row == 1
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.imageCell.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu.png"];
        cell.labelCell.text = @"not work";
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
     NSLog(@"count =%d",[self.menuItems count]);
    return cell;
}
```

> 2015-11-14 19:50:44.720 ScreenRides[13132:1185201] count =1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only seeing one row because there is only one object in your array.

Try:

```
self.menuItems = @[@"menu",@"favorite",@"animal",@"space",@"nature",@"car",@"minimal"];
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Please accept the answer if it resolves your issue

Answer (score -1):

Your all code is working perfect but There is small problem in your code while creating/assigning the values to an array. please check the following code and see whether you will see the 2nd Cell or not.

```
self.menuItems = @[@"menu",@"favorite",@"animal",@"spase",@"nature",@"car",@"minimal"];
```